# Jenkins table of parameters/global variables

Tags: arrays, powershell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins instance that has jobs that are heavily server biased. I am running tasks such as stop and start services, check message queues are active, copy files to particular locations, etc. I have a table that consists of various values associated with each server, such as name, RSA key, home location, process to control, and so on.

As an example, one pipeline first checks that five servers are active, restarts a process then runs a performance test. It looks like this;

```
node {
   stage('check_servers'){
      build job: "Check Server", parameters: [string(name: 'Server', value: 'server1@example.com'), string(name: 'home_location', value: '/opt/bob/carolgees/bin'), string(name: 'process', value: 'big_process')]
      build job: "Check Server", parameters: [string(name: 'Server', value: 'server2@example.com'), string(name: 'home_location', value: '/opt/bob/carolgees/bin'), string(name: 'process', value: 'bigger_process')]
      build job: "Check Server", parameters: [string(name: 'Server', value: 'server3@example.com'), string(name: 'home_location', value: '/opt/bob/holness/bin'), string(name: 'process', value: 'small_process')]
      build job: "Check Server", parameters: [string(name: 'Server', value: 'server4@example.com'), string(name: 'home_location', value: '/opt/bob/hope/bin'), string(name: 'process', value: 'smaller_process')]
      build job: "Check Server", parameters: [string(name: 'Server', value: 'server5@example.com'), string(name: 'home_location', value: '/opt/no/bob/bin'), string(name: 'process', value: 'what_process')]
   }
}
```

But this is getting very difficult to work with, especially as we work through and identify extra values that make the jobs more flexible. What I'd like to do is change the pipeline to;

```
node {
   stage('check_servers'){
      build job: "Check Server", parameters: [string(name: 'Server', value: 'server1@example.com')]
      build job: "Check Server", parameters: [string(name: 'Server', value: 'server2@example.com')]
      build job: "Check Server", parameters: [string(name: 'Server', value: 'server3@example.com')]
      build job: "Check Server", parameters: [string(name: 'Server', value: 'server4@example.com')]
      build job: "Check Server", parameters: [string(name: 'Server', value: 'server5@example.com')]
   }
}
```

Then have each job able to access a lookup table and use the Server name to access the other values required by the job.

Ideally I would like to be able to use the names in the script, something like;

```
echo $Server('server5@example.com').home_location
```

But I've no idea whether that is even a thing. The jobs are all Powershell scripts so it needs to be a Powershell based solution.

I can see solutions where a single string parameter is passed in that contains a delimited list of values, but again this isn't very flexible (I would need to change every job when I add a column).

Can anyone suggest an approach?

Comment: [Shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries) could be a good solution but you would need to inject groovy variables into your powershell scripts. Probably [withEnv {}](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables) can help to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Vitalii, your suggestion was enough to remind me of something I have used elsewhere. I've set up an XML file call ServerXmlContent as a config file which I can bring into each job. At the start of the Powershell job I have;

```
[xml]$content = Get-Content - Path $env:ServerXmlContent
```

This presents all the details in an XML object $content. Now all I need to do is Select-Xml to get the relevant server details from the server that is passed in from the pipeline;

```
[string]$home_location = Select-Xml -Xml $content -XPath "//server[hostname='$env:server']/home_location/text()" 
[string]$process = Select-Xml -Xml $content -XPath "//server[hostname='$env:server']/process/text()"
```